# how to fix Error: Cannot find module '../helper-hardhat-config'

Tags: solidity

[enterIn image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKkz3.png) How to fix this error of cannot find module??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mistake bro. You have written the file name incorrectly. Change `helper-hardhat-cofig.js` to `helper-hardhat-config.js`.

[image]

Comment: Bro Your problem solved or not?

Comment: Yeah spelling mistake was there thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved. Pls mark my answer as correct and upvote It will help me and other guys as well IA. Thanks.